# Handle URL Pattern Mapping for Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, url-pattern

I have web application developed in java with simple jsp and servlet.
And I have javascript files in it.
My Applications requirement is other applications can only hit my applications using a javascript file.

Example as: I have a starting javascript file as `http://<domain>/<ApplicationName>/<JSFileName>.js`.

Where I can configure this url with other applications to hit my application. But at the same time I don't want to specify the extension as `.js`. I want to configure the URL as `http://<domain>/<ApplicationName>/<JSFileName>` (means without the .js extension). I am reading about url patterns mappings for Javascript file, but didn't find anything.

Please suggest what can be possible idea to hide the .js extension from URL.

Comment: what do you mean by " other applications can only hit my applications using a javascript file."? calling directly your javascript would simply display the java script.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and came across your question, then came across this - https://libraries.io/bower/url-match